# activemq does not start

Tags: apache, ubuntu, activemq-classic, ubuntu-12.04

I have tries to follow the direction on the activemq site for downloading and running activemq: 
http://activemq.apache.org/getting-started.html#GettingStarted-StartingActiveMQ

I have downloaded the tar.gz file from here: http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=%2Factivemq%2Fapache-activemq%2F5.6.0%2Fapache-activemq-5.6.0-bin.tar.gz

I have extracted it and try to run bin\activemq from the extracted dir.

However for some reason the activemq does not start and I am keep getting the following error:

yosi@yosi:~/Downloads/apache-activemq-5.6.0$ ./bin/activemq start
INFO: Loading '/etc/default/activemq'
INFO: Using java '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_07/bin/java'
INFO: Starting - inspect logfiles specified in logging.properties and log4j.properties to get details
./bin/activemq: 396: ./bin/activemq: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_07/bin/java -Xms1G -Xmx1G -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote  -Djava.io.tmpdir="/home/yosi/Downloads/apache-activemq-5.6.0/tmp"                -Dactivemq.classpath="/home/yosi/Downloads/apache-activemq-5.6.0/conf;"               -Dactivemq.home="/home/yosi/Downloads/apache-activemq-5.6.0"               -Dactivemq.base="/home/yosi/Downloads/apache-activemq-5.6.0"               -Dactivemq.conf="/home/yosi/Downloads/apache-activemq-5.6.0/conf"               -Dactivemq.data="/home/yosi/Downloads/apache-activemq-5.6.0/data"                              -jar "/home/yosi/Downloads/apache-activemq-5.6.0/bin/run.jar" start >/dev/null 2>&1 &
              RET="$?"; APID="$!";
              echo $APID > /home/yosi/Downloads/apache-activemq-5.6.0/data/activemq-yosi.pid;
              **echo "INFO: pidfile created : '/home/yosi/Downloads/apache-activemq-5.6.0/data/activemq-yosi.pid' (pid '$APID')";exit $RET: not found**

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here? is it a problem in the activemq script?

Yosi

Comment: what platform are you running on?  did you change the start /bin/activemq script at all?

Comment: Question was marked as duplicate so I'm answering here (it's not really a duplicate, I ran into a similar issue):
If on a 64bit machine, try running the binary in /bin/linux-x86-64, not the one in /bin.

Comment: My error message locked similar to yours and I found the process described in this answer helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231640/activemq-will-not-start-on-my-ubuntu-vm

Answer (score 2):

are you sure its not running in the background?

```
ps -ef | grep activemq

tail -f ../data/activemq.log
```