# Unable to configure ActiveMQ web console in Ubuntu 18.x

Tags: java, apache

I followed this tutorial https://howtoprogram.xyz/2017/08/09/how-to-install-activemq-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-xenial-xerus/ to install ActiveMQ manually and everything worked fine and i was even able to access the webhost on http://127.0.0.1:8161. But I tried the `sudo apt-get install` automatic option out of curiosity and though it was also successful, I cannot access the web console for both installations now though I am able to start them. Below are snippets of the output:

```
● activemq.service - LSB: ActiveMQ instance
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/activemq; generated)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-03-28 22:52:17 GMT; 3s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
   Process: 14696 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/activemq stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCE
   Process: 15233 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/activemq start (code=exited, status=0/SUC
Tasks: 31 (limit: 4915)
CGroup: /system.slice/activemq.service
       └─15265 /usr/lib/jvm/default-java//bin/java -Xms512M -Xmx512M -Dorg.a
Mar 28 22:52:11 sys-abj systemd[1]: Starting LSB: ActiveMQ instance...
Mar 28 22:52:11 sys-abj activemq[15233]:  * Starting ActiveMQ instance  activemq
Mar 28 22:52:17 sys-abj activemq[15233]:    ...done.
Mar 28 22:52:17 sys-abj systemd[1]: Started LSB: ActiveMQ instance.
```

and a netstat to the transportConnector tells it's listening by yielding this result:

```
 tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:61616         :::*                    LISTEN      15265/java
```

However, any time I point to 127.0.0.1:8161, I get no feed back.

I stumbled upon this [How to install or config activemq admin cosole(jetty) use apt-get command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020283/how-to-install-or-config-activemq-admin-cosolejetty-use-apt-get-command) link but I still can't wrap my head around how to configure the web console.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Is anything listening on port 8161? do a `$ netstat -an  | grep LISTEN`

Comment: No, nothing is. I know for sure that the problem has to do with configuring the jetty.xml file and adding it in the activemq.xml file. I don't know how to go about that. A few articles have made it clear that the "sudo apt-get install" doesn't pre-install every component

Comment: I've got a ubuntu vm lying around somewhere, I'll see if I can work it out..

Comment: I've been able to fix it but if you're still  able to configure it, kindly share for another person who gets stuck. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to fix it!

I deleted ActiveMQ and its accompanying dependencies by running `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove activemq`, downloaded the zip file again from https://activemq.apache.org/download.html and unzipped it to my preferred destination.

I wouldn't recommend anyone running the `sudo apt-get install activemq` command if you're not sure of what you're doing

Comment: I think the manually downloaded one was probably still running when you were looking at the apt-get installed version. The apt-get version doesn't contain much other than the bare bones broker, for more info look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020283/how-to-install-or-config-activemq-admin-cosolejetty-use-apt-get-command