# Apache ActiveMQ 5.11.1 doesn't start in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, activemq-classic

I am a newbie to Apache ActiveMQ. I am following the instructions from [here](http://activemq.apache.org/unix-shell-script.html#UnixShellScript-Version5.11.0andhigher)

I don't need multiple instances of ActiveMQ. I'm just trying a HelloWorld using ActiveMQ. But when I start I get the following below error:

```
vinod@BBLPT0326:/srv/activemq/current$ /etc/init.d/activemq start
INFO: Loading '/etc/default/activemq'
INFO: Using java '/opt/software/java/bin/java'
INFO: Starting - inspect logfiles specified in logging.properties and log4j.properties to get details
/etc/init.d/activemq: 300: /etc/init.d/activemq: "/opt/software/java/bin/java" -Xms1G -Xmx1G -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/srv/activemq/apache-activemq-5.11.1/conf/login.config  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote  -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.io.tmpdir="/srv/activemq/apache-activemq-5.11.1/tmp"                -Dactivemq.classpath="/srv/activemq/apache-activemq-5.11.1/conf:"               -Dactivemq.home="/srv/activemq/apache-activemq-5.11.1"               -Dactivemq.base="/srv/activemq/apache-activemq-5.11.1"               -Dactivemq.conf="/srv/activemq/apache-activemq-5.11.1/conf"               -Dactivemq.data="/srv/activemq/apache-activemq-5.11.1/data"                              -jar "/srv/activemq/apache-activemq-5.11.1/bin/activemq.jar" start /dev/null 2>&1 &
              RET="$?"; APID="$!";
              echo $APID > /srv/activemq/apache-activemq-5.11.1/data/activemq.pid;
              echo "INFO: pidfile created : '/srv/activemq/apache-activemq-5.11.1/data/activemq.pid' (pid '$APID')";exit $RET: not found
```

When tried with `sudo` I get a different error:

```
vinod@BBLPT0326:/srv/activemq/current$ sudo /etc/init.d/activemq start

INFO: Loading '/etc/default/activemq'
ERROR: Configuration variable JAVA_HOME or JAVACMD is not defined correctly.
       (JAVA_HOME='', JAVACMD='java')
```

My `JAVA_HOME` is defined. I verified the same as below.

```
vinod@BBLPT0326:/srv/activemq/current$ echo $JAVA_HOME

/opt/software/java
```

I already referred solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231640/activemq-will-not-start-on-my-ubuntu-vm) as I am using Ubuntu 14.0.4.

But I am not really clear as I don't have a path `/etc/activemq/instances-enabled` and from where should I execute the command `sudo ln -s ../instances-available/main/`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am answering my own question here.

In ubuntu 14.0.4 root cause of the problem is

***INFO: Loading '/etc/default/activemq' ERROR: Configuration variable JAVA_HOME or JAVACMD is not defined correctly. (JAVA_HOME='', JAVACMD='java')***

Even if you define JAVA_HOME in /etc/environment, active MQ reads only from either of the below locations where ever if finds the file first.

1. /etc/default/activemq
2. $HOME/.activemqrc
3. $INSTALLDIR/apache-activemq-/bin/env

So I recommend defining JAVA_HOME in /etc/default/activemq (which is copied from $INSTALLDIR/apache-activemq-/bin/env)

I did as below

JAVA_HOME="/opt/software/java/jre"
JAVACMD="/opt/software/java/jre/bin/java"

Comment: JAVA_HOME="/opt/software/java/jre" JAVACMD="/opt/software/java/jre/bin/java" did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

If you are just needing jre instead of the whole jdk then reinstalling jre worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre-headless
```